# Is spring MVC purposed for web pages?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to build a server for my android application.

My application lets users register and allows each user to request a list of all users registered to my application, so my server will be mainly in charge of receiving data from a user, updating the database, and sending data back to user on request.

Since I've never built a server I looked into what would be the ideal way to achieve my goals and after some reading I've found that Spring would be the right way to go, But I also found that there are all kinds of springs.

Eventually I've narrowed my options down to Spring MVC and spring Boot,
I've read that spring boot is a good start but I also read that spring boot does all the configurations for you and I want to really know how stuff works so I fear that spring boot will do all the work for me , So I thought of maybe using spring MVC but I couldn't completely figure out if Spring MVC would be good to achieve my goals or if it's mainly used for building web pages

So what would be the best suitable spring to use ?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer Spring boot. It's not just about it doing all the configuration for you. It's about `Spring` saving you from writing a lot of boilerplate code (you still have to do a fair bit of configuration though). Plus, it will be easy to spin up the app and test it locally (you can even test it with local file based `h2` database, meaning you don't need to install any database into your machine).

Adding Spring Data JPA dependency with Spring boot will take care of persistent layer as well. And if you want to write `jsp` or `html` pages then I would recommend having a look at this [thymeleaf](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-thymeleaf/) example.

[Here's](https://github.com/darshanmehta10/app-offer) the sample CRUD application I have developed with Spring boot and [here's](http://techblog-dm.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/spring-boot-boot-unnecessary-things-off.html) my own blog about it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring MVC stands for model,view,controller. View, in general is something which is returned after your business logic has been executed and mainly suggests webpages. Spring Boot would be the easiest way to set up your server for the application. However, if you want to know how things work you can go with the basic spring. Spring, too provided classes like `JdbcTemplate` to reduce your boilerplate code, however it forces you to configure things yourself. 
You do not have the comfort of annotating a resource and watching as the magic happens. If you want to speed up setting up a server and make things less complex go for Spring Boot.